# RequestMapping in xml

Tags: spring-mvc

I am new to Spring MVC 3.0, I have a background of struts 2.0.
I am comfortable with configuration in xml.

So, I am looking for a way to represent to @RequestMapping in the springdispatcher-servlet.xml or any other dependent xml.

**Is there a way to move the @RequestMapping annotations to xml file?**

As a side question,

**what is the benefit of @RequestMapping on individual methods over struts single point of entry per Action?**

*Below is a sample class:*

```
@Controller
public class ContentController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/content", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView getContent() {
        // do something
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/savecontent", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView getSaveContent() {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue with spring, the spring ticket is listed below.
It also discusses the issue in good detail.

[SPR-5757](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-5757)

Answer (score 12):

Not only is this possible, it was the only way to do it pre-Spring 2.5. Rather bizarrely, pretty much all mention of this has been removed from the Spring ref manual, even though it's still a perfectly valid way of mapping your requests.  The only mention of it I can stil lfind is section [15.4.1](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-handlermapping-interceptor).

A simple example is:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
   <property name="mappings">
      <map>
         <entry key="/doSomething/**" value-ref="controllerA"/>
         <entry key="/other Thing/**" value-ref="controllerB"/>
      </map>
   </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: Thank you, I have used a similar thing to map simple Controllers that implement Controller and have handleRequest method to handle all requests. But the @RequestMapping are declare on a per method basis. I have edited the question with a sample class showing this implementation. Is there any way to map that as well. Please advice.

Comment: How to map `/doSomething/**` url to specific method of Spring controller `controllerA`?

Comment: hi skaffman, is there any source where I can find all the spring configuration in XML? The use case is I want to replace all the annotations like #RequestMapping, #RequestParam etc with XML configuration.