# Spring MVC 3.0.7 in Liferay - ActionMapping without annotations

Tags: spring, liferay

I would like to make the same mapping as :

```
@Controller 
@RequestMapping ("VIEW") 
public class MyController extends AbstractController { 

@RenderMapping (params = "action=changePage") 
public String changePage (@ModelAttribute () final MyFormulaire form, final RenderRequest renderRequest, final RenderResponse renderResponse, final Model model) {
 return "test";
    } 
}
```

but without using annotations and by configuring all the beans and mapping using xml.
Is it possible to do such a thing ? I didn't find documentation about mapping params in spring xml files.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a question asked before similar to yours, here is the link; https://stackoverflow.com/a/4497616/1241311

An example of how to do it pre-spring 2.5;

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
   <property name="mappings">
      <map>
         <entry key="/doSomething/**" value-ref="controllerA"/>
         <entry key="/otherThing/**" value-ref="controllerB"/>
      </map>
   </property>
</bean>
```

It seems this is a known issue and there is an improvment ticket, you can find more info in here; [SPR-5757](https://jira.springframework.org/browse/SPR-5757)

Comment: My use of an xml based configuration was to use the same controller class in multiple bean with some configuration and configuring the mapping in xml.
Thanks for the issue. It seems I don't have the choice to make n Controller extending my first one to redefine the Annotations ...

Comment: You can use variables in the requestmapping. So you wouldnt need to extend your controller. Check out pathvariables