# Spring 4 No mapping found for HTTP request

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-mvc

I'm running Spring 4 and am trying to build a VERY basic REST web service as a proof of concept. Here is my web.xml:

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app id="poc" version="2.4"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee
                        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

    <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>ws</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ws</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/ws-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>
</web-app>
```

Here's the definition of my servlet in my application context:

http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd">

```
<bean name="/rememberName" class="com.corrisoft.air.ws.RememberNameController" init-method="init">
    <property name="personService" ref="personService"/>
</bean>
```

Here are the messages I'm getting from Spring:

```
INFO: Mapped URL path [/rememberName] onto handler '/rememberName'
....
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/springpoc/ws/rememberName] in DispatcherServlet with name 'ws'
```

Where springpoc is the name of the war file I'm deploying under tomcat. RememberNameController directly extends HttpServlet.

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong with my mapping?

Comment: Please share applicationContext.xml too so we can see what viewresolvers you have and how they are configured.

Comment: Added the application context as you requested.

Comment: I think it's complaining that you didn't bind it to the correct url. You can invoke it using something like localhost:8080/springpoc/rememberName or if you make the change I suggested below, localhost:8080/springpoc/ws/rememberName

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ws</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

needs to be this:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ws</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/ws/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Answer (score 1):

Spring controllers should not extend `HttpServlet`, they should be built with Spring annotations. e.g.

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class HelloWorldController {

    @RequestMapping("/hello")
    public String hello() {
        return "helloworld";
    }
}
```

See the following tutorial for details http://javahash.com/spring-4-mvc-hello-world-tutorial-full-example/

Comment: I know they show that a lot. How do you build your controllers with your XML file that way?

Comment: I did this in my Spring app. You don't need to do anything in your XML files. The DispatcherServlet maps requests to your POJOs auto-freakin-magically. Spring is wonderful.

Comment: If you really want to configure request mapping in XML, here is an example

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481373/requestmapping-in-xml

Comment: Basically, what these guys are saying is that if you use DispatcherServlet, you don't subclass it. You declare it in your xml files as you have done, then create an object with an Controller annotation and a RequestMapping (for the class or a particular method). It is, as I say, magic.

Comment: @mttdbrd My point is that I want to configure my stuff in my XML files. I don't like annotation based auto-wiring. Magic always comes with a price, deary.

Comment: @TheThom please see the link I posted into comments on how to wire controllers together with XML. However the controller still should not extend HttpServlet. If you are writing servlets directly there is no need for Spring.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you are mixing what is intended to be a Spring Controller with plain Servlets.
Spring Controllers are not Servlets, they are regular POJOs that are used by Spring MVC for handling the requests (called by the Dispatcher Servlet)

If you want to see a modern way of creating a REST Service using Spring 4, check out [this guide](http://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/)