# Why Spring RequestMapping not working without @Controller?

Tags: java, xml, spring

Sample code I have:

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" version="3.0">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>springDispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>springDispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

**springDispatcher-servlet.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd">
    <bean id="myController" class="biz.tugay.springWebOne.MyController"/>
</beans>
```

**MyController.java**

```
package biz.tugay.springWebOne;
/* User: koray@tugay.biz Date: 08/07/15 Time: 15:25 */

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class MyController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/hello")
    public String helloWorld(){
        return "index.jsp";
    }
}
```

Well, everything works fine with this code. However when I remove the

```
 @Controller
```

from **MyController** class I will get:

```
HTTP ERROR 404

Problem accessing /hello. Reason:

    Not Found
```

I am not using **component-scan**, I am using an xml based configuration. Why do I need the @Controller annotation?

Comment: Since `@Controller` is an integral part of request mapping configuration (contains defaults for the whole class), this isn't too surprising.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from spring reference documentation [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-ann-controller)

> The @Controller annotation acts as a stereotype for the annotated
>   class, indicating its role. The **dispatcher** scans such annotated
>   classes for mapped methods and detects @RequestMapping annotations

so **@Controller** is required to tell **dispatcher** to scan mapping in this class not only for component scan.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using component scanning, Spring will not know where to scan for @RequestMapping without the @Controller annotation.  If you would like to configure your requestmappings with XML, that should be able to be done similar to one of the answers here: [@RequestMapping with XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481373/requestmapping-in-xml)

Answer (score 0):

Your example will not work because the `@Controller` annotation is essentially the "entry point" telling the component scanner to scan this class, without `@Controller` all other spring controller annotations (eg. `@RequestMapping`) will be ignored.

I noticed that you pointed out that you are not using component-scan and you are using xml-based configuration, but in reality you are attempting to mix xml-based and annotation-based configuration for a single class, which will lead to very sloppy code. I would recommend removing your xml bean definition and using only the `@Controller` annotation and adding the `component-scan` tag in your xml to clean up your code.

If you decide you still want to do xml only configuration you should remove the `@RequestMapping` annotation and replace it with the following xml.

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
   <property name="mappings">
      <map>
         <entry key="/hello" value-ref="myController"/>
      </map>
   </property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use Spring without annotations, so you can use a BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping to indicate the controller class to the Dispatcher. So, just add the following bean to your XML and you do not have to include the @Controller anymore:

```
<bean id="handlerMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping"/>
```